# How to have a matrix as paramater when working with CUDA and Matlab

Tags: c++, windows, matlab, matrix, cuda

I'm trying to figure out how to pass a matrix from Matlab to a C++ CUDA file (*.ptx).
I want to process the matrix differently in every thread! I definitely don't want to split the matrix up in different threads! I want each thread to have the same matrix!

[Matlab and CUDA (C++)](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/distcomp/run-cuda-or-ptx-code-on-gpu.html#bsies_q)

I've tried something like:

```
_global_ void radialAverage(int* image[][]) {
  ...
}
```

but it didn't work. I am getting the following error:

```
kernel.cu(8): error: an array may not have elements of this type
1 error detected in the compilation of "C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Loca/Temp/tmpxft_00000c44_00000000-8_kernel.cpp1.ii".
```

Can you think of any way to do this? Or is it possible?

Btw: I'm not using any libraries for C++, only the CUDA-Api.

Comment: Can you post the error you are receiving?

Comment: kernel.cu(8): error: an array may not have elements of this type

1 error detected in the compilation of "C:/Users/ADMINI~1/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpxft_00000c44_00000000-8_kernel.cpp1.ii".

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of defining the kernel to pass a matrix from Matlab is clearly shown (several times) on the page you linked to in your question.

In summary, define the kernel like this (the Matlab `gpuArray` is passed automagically as a device pointer to the kernel):

```
__global__ void radialAverage(int* image) {
  ...
}
```

After you retrieve the kernel using `CUDAKernel` from the toolbox, create an integer  `gpuArray` from your Matlab matrix, and pass that to the kernel function.

Comment: When I tried your solution I got the error: "kernel.cu(55): error: expression must have pointer-to-object type" I think this is because he doesn't accept the Pointer as an multidimensional Array!

Comment: You cannot use `[][]` style indexing inside CUDA kernels for an array passed by pointer. This error is effectively a different question - "How can I index a Matlab array inside a kernel". Please update your question with some real code.....

Comment: Ok so it was the way I wanted to access the data! Thank you for your help! I think I'll open a new Question for that :D